# What's the equivalent of std::is_const for references to const?

Tags: c++, types, constants

Consider the code:

```
int const  x = 50;
int const& y = x;
cout << std::is_const<decltype(x)>::value << endl; // 1
cout << std::is_const<decltype(y)>::value << endl; // 0
```

This makes sense, because `y` is not a `const` reference, it is a reference to a `const`.

Is there a `foo` such that `std::foo<decltype(y)>::value` is 1? If not, what would it look like to define my own?

Comment: Does `std::remove_reference` help?

Comment: Surely you mean `std::is_const<decltype(x)>::value`? And `std::is_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(y)>::type>::value` produces the value you're looking for.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [remove_reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int const  x = 50;
    int const& y = x;
    cout << std::is_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(x)>::type>::value << endl; // 1
    cout << std::is_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(y)>::type>::value << endl; // 1

    return 0;
}
```

[See on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4bb053a8fb701cc)

Comment: Why remove reference to a not reference integer?

Comment: @WhyCry To show that it works whether or not the underlying thing is a reference or not. I'm assuming OP was looking for a general solution.

Comment: `cout << std::is_const<decltype(x)>::value << endl;` // 1
`cout << std::is_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(y)>::type>::value << endl;`

So these are essentially the same in a less general sense. (My conclusions)

Comment: remove_reference has no effect if T is not a reference, as stated in the documentation.

Comment: Would putting an even more generalized version be a valid answer to this question?

Comment: @WhyCry Here's something even easier: `cout << 1 << endl; cout << 1 << endl;` :) If you have the luxury of knowing types a priori then why bother with type traits at all? If you want a general solution that works when the type maybe `const`, or reference to `const`, then you need something like the code above.

Comment: I understand it now, I was just trying to apply it in a more general sense where instead of `decltype(variable)`, one could just add `int const` or `int const &`. I'm not arguing, just applying it within my own context in my editor` for my **own** understanding :).

Comment: @WhyCry Substituting decltype(x)/decltype(y) for the real types works too [as you can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da97b64d421e5b1e)

Comment: I'm not saying it's not. I was simply stating how generically this can be applied! I'm complementing the power of the code of your answer, not pushing it down.